# substring on TEXT type returns NULL through OLEDB / SSIS

Tags: ssis, oledbconnection

I'm trying to extract the first 120 characters of a `DT_TEXT` column in a SQL 2008 database. My SQL statement works fine and returns desired results in SQL Management Studio.

However, when the query runs in SSIS using an OLEDB Source component, it returns all nulls. Everything is identical - same exact server, database, and table. Same SQL Statement cut-and-pasted into the OLEDB Source. Here's what it looks like:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ColA, 1, 120) AS MyCol from MyTable
```

`ColA` is a `DT_TEXT` data type.

Does anyone know why this statement doesn't return any data when it runs through the OLEDB Connection in SSIS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried casting the data to varchar?

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(ColA, 1, 120) as varchar(120)) AS MyCol from MyTable
```

That should force the oledb component to change the meta data about the column to `DT_STR` and things should work from there on. Seems odd the source component didn't get it right in the first place but I've never worked with the text data type.